# PowerShell can't divide a value on some systems

Tags: powershell, math

Having a very strange problem. I have two systems (my desktop and my laptop). Both are running Windows 10 and PowerShell 5.1. On my desktop, the division works without problem, but on my laptop, I get the below op_Division error where it says that it is an object (but the division works fine on the other system). I tried somehow converting the object to a string, but everything I tried failed.

Can anyone advise how I can get this to divide on the system that is failing (and why it works *without problem* on the other system)?

```
$width = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DesktopMonitor | Select-Object ScreenWidth).ScreenWidth
$width = $width / 2

#####

Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $width = $width / 2
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Division:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: You're attempting to divide a non-number by a number.  `$width` is a System.Object array.  I'm going to give a wild guess: On the non-working systems, do you have multiple monitors, and the systems that work have one screen?

Comment: That's a very good assumption, but no, both are single monitor (and no virtual hidden monitors showing in Display properties). But you are right even though I can't see hidden monitors. On further prodding I've got a fix, I have to select [1] from the array on the laptop. hmm, I should have seen, ok, I'll iterate through the array and only act on non-zero values or something I think. Thanks.
`$width = ((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DesktopMonitor | Select-Object ScreenWidth).ScreenWidth)[1]`

Comment: I'd look at array position [0] as well.  [0] is typically the 'start' of any array, but I'm curious what results you get in either position.

Comment: yeah, I tried 0 first of course, and that returns a null for me, so the laptop is generating an non-visible virtual monitor - I think from when it was plugged into a monitor at work that it is remembering that

Comment: This could be happening because `$width` is an array. If you run `$width.PsObject` you can see the `BaseObject` value will be a collection possibly containing `$null`. When you run `$width[0]` you may be returning the `$null` value. You will need to use another index.

Answer (score 1):

This could be happening because `$width` is an array. If you run `$width.PsObject` you can see the `BaseObject` value will be a collection possibly containing `$null`. When you run `$width[0]` you may be returning the `$null` value. You will need to use another index with your current code.

However, you could filter out the `$null` values from the beginning with `Where`.

```
$width = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DesktopMonitor | Where ScreenWidth).ScreenWidth
$width = $width | Foreach-Object { $_ / 2 }
```

With your attempt, at least on my system, `$width` returns an array.

```
$width.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

$width
1920
$width.PsObject | Select-Object BaseObject

BaseObject
----------
{$null, 1920}

$width[0] # Index 0 contains the $null
$width[1] # Index 1 contains the size
1920
```

Comment: I'm trying to calculate these dimensions so that I can open a half size RDP session:

    `$widths = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DesktopMonitor | Select-Object ScreenWidth).ScreenWidth` ;
    `$heights = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DesktopMonitor | Select-Object ScreenHeight).ScreenHeight` ;
    
    `$width = 0 ; foreach ($i in $widths) { if ($i -ne $null -and $i -ne 0) { $width = $i } }` ;
    `$height = 0 ; foreach ($i in $heights) { if ($i -ne $null -and $i -ne 0) { $height = $i } }` ;

    `$width = ($width / 2) - 5` ;
    `$height = $height - 107   # Start Bar 74, 107 is right`

Comment: It seems like that logic would work as long as `$widths` and `$heights` produce one numerical non-zero value. The problem you presented in the post does not reflect this code exactly. One question becomes, what if `$widths` and `$heights` have multiple non-zero numerical values?

Comment: For now, I'm just being loose on that. It will populate `$width` / `$height` with the last non-zero/non-null monitor that it finds, then I can take my 2x RDP windows that I generate and push them onto that screen (if they don't appear on that screen, 50% chance). Afterwards, I want to get more exacting, and would like to decide where the new windows will appear and then *position* them to the left and right of the screen (if I can find out how to do that in PowerShell ... any tips would be very appreciated! ;-) ).

Comment: I'm planning on using something like this to position things. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-the-position-and-size-54853527

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple monitors and Get-WMIObject is returning an array so use this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DesktopMonitor | Select-Object ScreenWidth | ForEach {
  [Double]$width = [Double]$_.ScreenWidth[0]
  $width = $width / 2
}
```

Comment: But OP doesn't have multiple monitors... see the comments above, and this code actually gives me several "Cannot index into a null array" errors right off the bat.